# form validation not alerting after checking conditions

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate an HTML form with javascript, but since no alerts were popping up I thought my checkSubmit() function wasn't being called.  However, after adding an additional alert at the beginning of the function it is indeed firing but no further alerts pop up after checking the first condition.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function checkSubmit() {

     alert("Hello from Javascript!");
     if (document.getElementById("user").value.toString.length <1) {
        alert("Please enter a user name.");
        return false;
     }

     if (document.getElementById("location").value.toString.length <1) {
        alert("Please enter a location.");
        return false;
     }
     if (document.getElementById("depart").value.toString.length <1) {
        alert("Please enter a department.");
        return false;
     }
     if (document.getElementById("category").value.toString.length <1) {
        alert("Please enter a problem type.");
        return false;
     }
     if (document.getElementById("info").value.toString.length <1) {
        alert("Please enter a problem description.");
        return false;
     }
     alert("Hello from Javascript2!");
     return true;
   }   
</script>

<form name="submit" type="submit" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkSubmit();">

   [...]

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Unless I made an error (which I'm sure will be obvious in hindsight), shouldn't there be a second alert pop up, regardless if any of the conditions are true or false?

Comment: Do you get an error reported in the console?  Maybe not finding one of your controls...

Comment: I guess you got an error like value is not defined.

Comment: Aha.  I was missing the "id=" tag in my first input box.  However, now I'm getting the opposite problem - I'm getting an alert to enter a user name even when the box with the id "user" has text in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `toString` because `.value` will already be a string, and you are using it incorrectly anyway - you need to say `.toString()`. As it is, it returns the function definition, so `.length` will be `0`. And as you say, you need to set the `id` attribute for each box correctly.

```
function checkSubmit() {

    if (document.getElementById("user").value.length < 1) {
        alert("Please enter a user name.");
        return false;
     }

     if (document.getElementById("location").value.length < 1) {
        alert("Please enter a location.");
        return false;
     }

     if (document.getElementById("depart").value.length < 1) {
        alert("Please enter a department.");
        return false;
     }

     if (document.getElementById("category").value.length < 1) {
        alert("Please enter a problem type.");
        return false;
     }

     if (document.getElementById("info").value.length < 1) {
        alert("Please enter a problem description.");
        return false;
     }

     return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works now.  Hope this question helps others who went down the blind alley of thinking their "onsubmit" wasn't working, because the page was originally appearing to submit/refresh without any other actions.